# How to solve PostgreSQL authentication problem?

Tags: postgresql

### I am getting error after converting project

- DB writer thread failed due to ERROR: Connection to database failed: SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above

### Here is my postgresql version :

- PostgreSQL 14.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit

Comment: You need to upgrade the libraries your _application_ is using.

Comment: Can you tell me how to upgrade?

Comment: @bin how did you install the library? No language comes with database drivers out of the box. A programmer has to add them explicitly. What language and library are you using? The error says that a new version of `libpq` is needed which means either you wrote a C program or are using a library that depends on libpq

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos how can i upgrade the library libpq

Comment: How did you add it in the first place? Same way. If you downloaded the library, download a new version. If you used a package manager, update the package. You haven't even told us what language you use

Comment: I use java language. I am trying to convert an OSM pbf file to osm2pgsql for use in nominatim

Comment: Use the latest JDBC driver then. That error message is not from the JDBC driver, however.

Comment: I tried several ways but it didn't work